# How to identify dynamic text using column expressions

Tags: c#, datatable, expression, calculated-columns

*first, the title might not fit that well. I was not quite sure how to summarize it the best. I hope it is not misleading.*

I have a datatable which includes a column with values from an http request.

| ID | DynamicContent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"DynamicProperties":{"Name":"John Doe","Birthday":"24.12.2021"}} |
| 2 | {"DynamicProperties":{"Name":"Jane Doe","Birthday":"21.12.2021"}} |

I now want to dynamically add a new "calculated" column for each value in an Array {"Name", "Birthday"}.
Column name should be the string from the array and the value should be the value from the string in the DynamicContent column.
The final datatable should look like this.

| ID | DynamicContent | Name | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"DynamicProperties":{"Name":"John Doe","Birthday":"24.12.2021"}} | John Doe | 24.12.2021 |
| 2 | {"DynamicProperties":{"Name":"Jane Doe","Birthday":"21.12.2021"}} | Jane Doe | 21.12.2021 |

Would this be able with some kind of column Expression in combination with regex? Or is there another aproach that could help me here? I did not work with column expressions before.

Comment: Do you use ORM (Entity Framework or Dapper) in your project?

Comment: No. It is in fact no "real" c# project. It is an RPA project which uses c# as programming language in the background. Just wondering if my problem could be solved somehow with c# as it is to me kind of a specific problem.

Comment: Please review this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0). You need to use string functions like `SUBSTRING`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide more info I made it work with DataTable object, note that this may not work depending on what library are you using to communicate with the database.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.Json;

public static void Main()
    {
        var myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Birthday", typeof(DateTime));
        foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(row["DynamicProperties"].ToString());
            var name = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("DynamicProperties")
                                      .GetProperty("Name").GetString();
            var birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(doc.RootElement.GetProperty("DynamicProperties")
                              .GetProperty("Birthday").GetString(), "dd.mm.yyyy", null);
        
        row["Name"] = name;
        row["Birthday"] = birthday;
    }
}
```